# Redirecting my site is not working

Tags: apache-2.4, https, ubuntu-14.04, 301-redirect

Ubuntu 14.04 and Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Ubuntu)

The redirect rule is not working or am I missing something ? When I type in the browser, I want to use https://teampass.domain.org,  but instead https://teampass.domain.org/teampass is the only url that works. Am I missing something? How can I get to use https://teampass.domain.org

more /etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
 127.0.1.1       teampass
 192.*.*.*   teampass       teampass.domain.org

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
 ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
 ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

More /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
  ServerRoot "/etc/apache2"

 Mutex file:${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} default

 PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

 Timeout 300


  KeepAlive On

  MaxKeepAliveRequests 100

  KeepAliveTimeout 15


# These need to be set in /etc/apache2/envvars
 User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
 Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

  HostnameLookups Off

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log


   LogLevel warn

 # Include module configuration:
 IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load

 IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

  # Include list of ports to listen on
  Include ports.conf


    <Directory />

    Options FollowSymLinks

    AllowOverride None

    Require all denied

   </Directory>


  <Directory /usr/share>

    AllowOverride None

    Require all granted

   </Directory>

   <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
    Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <Directory /srv/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
     </Directory>


  AccessFileName .htaccess


  <FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
   </FilesMatch>



 # Include generic snippets of statements
 IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

  # Include the virtual host configurations:
   IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

# phpMyAdmin Configuration
 Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf

 #load ssl module
 #LoadModule ssl_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so
```

more /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName teampass.domain.org
    Serveralias www.teampass.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on

    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
    SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
</VirtualHost>
```

more /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/teampass.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName teampass
  Redirect permanent /  https://teampass.domain.org/

  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass
  <Directory /var/www/html>
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # DO NOT REMOVE
            RewriteOptions Inherit
    </IfModule>
   </VirtualHost>


   <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName teampass.domain.org
    #ServerAlias www.teampass.domain.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/teampass

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/star_domain_org
    SSLCertificateKeyfile /etc/apache2/ssl/teampass.key
    SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/DigiCertCA
    SSLEngine on
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/teampass_access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            # DO NOT REMOVE
           RewriteOptions Inherit
    </IfModule>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You have server name teampass.domain.org configured for both the virtual hosts but with different path.  Here are a few suggestions, 1. disable default-ssl virutal site with a2dis command, 2. create two seperate conf files for port 80 and port 443 for the same site and enable them and try to reach the site with http and https and see.

Comment: Also you need check for proper syntax for apache 2.4 for your virtual hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

The virtual host configuration for your site `teampass.domain.org` is not going to work the way it has both http and https on the same virtual host site (teampass.conf).

You have the same server name `teampass.domain.org` for the `default-ssl` site, that's why it is working and you can reach the site but not as you want, because the DocumentRoot points to `/var/www/html`.

You can either change the DocumentRoot to `/var/www/html/teampass` in your default-ssl file and disable the other virtual host file.

Or, you need to create two different sites (with two .conf files and enable them) for http (80) and https (ssl) and disable the default-ssl site.

You also need to correct some syntax for `Options` for apache 2.4.

Comment: Thank you @bangal . i decided to take change the DocumentRoot to /var/www/html/teampass in default-ssl site . I disabled all sites but default-ssl. now the problem am facing is, the default-ssl site is serving 80 instead of 443.

Comment: Do you mean, you get http://teampass.domin.org? Can you check your apache error log at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and also put this line `LoadModule ssl_module   modules/mod_ssl.so` in the default-ssl file.

Comment: Were you able to browse https://teampass.domain.org with ssl before?

Comment: no errors in the log. and yes teampass.domain.org works with ssl.  I decided to enable my old teampass.conf which has both 80 and 443  but with 80 redirect url to 443. and it works fine with teampass.domain.org/teampass.   I created two seperate sites for 80 and 443. , enabled them and they all server only 80 so disabled both and just enabled teampass.conf site.

Comment: Well, forgive me, i didn't understand you fully and I guess I have mentioned very clearly the problem in my answer. So is your problem solved now?